# AngularJS Directive update parent with an iteration late

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive, that use an isolation scope

```
priceApp.directive("clickToEdit", function() {
    var editorTemplate = '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
        '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '{{value}} ' +
            '<a ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '<input ng-model="view.editableValue">' +
            '<a ng-click="saveValue()">Save</a>' +
            ' or ' +
            '<a ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        template: editorTemplate,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            value: "=clickToEdit",
        },
        link: function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
            $scope.view = {
                editableValue: $scope.value,
                editorEnabled: false
            };

            $scope.enableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
                $scope.view.editableValue = $scope.value;
            };

            $scope.disableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
            };

            $scope.saveValue = function() {
                $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue;
                $scope.disableEditor();
                $scope.$emit('update');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

In HTML it's used like

```
<div ng-controller="productDetailController" class="product-title">
    <div click-to-edit="product.name"></div>
</div>
```

And my controller has:

```
$scope.$on('update',function(){
    saveProduct($scope.product);
});
```

Very interesting is that value from $scope.$on is with an iteration back...
if now I put  value "test 1" in field and call save method from directive I get old value (initial value), after this if I put "test 2", in controller I get "text 1".
I want to know where it's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a hack using $timeout

```
$scope.$on('update',function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        saveProduct($scope.product);
    }, 0);      
});
```